# Edit linux capabilities in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, linux-capabilities

In a C program, you can edit your capabilities with `cap_set_proc` from `libcap`. How can I achieve the same in a Perl program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Linux::Prctl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Linux-Prctl/) may meet your needs.

If not, you can use [syscall()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syscall.html) and try to [do it the hard way](http://michael.toren.net/slides/perl-syscall/).

If that's unpalatable, too (and I would find it so), I'm sure CPAN would welcome you to contribute Linux::CapNG bindings...

Comment: @pilcrow: heh. +1 on CapNG bindings ;)